# Passing values between activities properly

Tags: android

Hello I am new to android and I have a problem I do not know how to solve.  I have 3 activities, **ActivityMain**, **ActivityA** and **ActivityB**.  ActivityMain is the **start activity**.  From ActivityMain the user can move to ActivityA, when they do that a value is passed from ActivityMain to ActivityA like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, ActivityA.class);
i.putExtra("eventId", eventId);
startActivity(i);
```

And in my onCreate method of **ActivityA** I have an **init()** function that gets that value like this:

```
public void init() {
  this.eventId = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().get("eventId").toString());
}
```

Now this is my issue, for some reason when I navigate from **ActivityA** to **ActivityB** then I click back my app stops working a **Null Pointer Exception** is thrown at the above line of code.

Comment: Check for null value for intent and the integer you are retrieving from intent

Comment: Not essential to the answer, but you should catch the NumberFormatException.....

Comment: i.putExtras("eventId", eventId); try this code....

Comment: Can you post exception stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

Cache the data from "Extra" to a variable - use onResume() method in your activity to set any configurations.

Comment: I can't understand though why onCreate() is called when I press back, is that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: That is correct - Activity lifecycle has a hierarchy which gets followed - onStop is called when activity goes behind and returns - see here for more details - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: One has to use "onResume" and "onCreate" handle that the OS provides - you could put a check ("if" statement) to determine whether an instance of your activity is already in the backstack and skip obtaining the "bundle" through getInt/getBoolean

Answer (score 1):

if you pass integer try something like this

```
this.eventId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("eventId");
```

or if you pass string. try this

```
this.eventId = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().getString("eventId"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are passing data to intent directly and trying to access it from intent bundle but not intent. Use `intent.getIntExtra("eventId")`

Replace:

```
Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().get("eventId").toString());
```

With

```
eventId = getIntent().getIntExtra("eventId");
```

**Secondly if you eventId is integer then use intent.getIntExtra, if eventId is string then use intent.getStringExtra**

Comment: Thanks, I saw no "getInt()" function though, there was getIntExtra and it took two parameters.

Comment: So you have that reason not to accept the answer ;) It's ok

Comment: That didn't solve my problem though, looks like the issue wasn't with how I was passing the value but the activity getting destroyed when I moved to the next activity to conserve memory so whenever I navigated back onCreate was called first instead of onStart.